# Is there a way to programatically stop gatling test?

Tags: gatling

I have a requirement where I need to run the test until all the data items from the feeder is exhausted. i.e. stop the exection after gatling has iterated through all the data. How to achieve this? I only understand how to stop it after certain duration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gatling automatically stops when feeders are exhausted, so you have nothing special to do on your side.

Comment: Note that then, it will force shutdown as feeder starvation is considered a fatal error and won't generate the reports. But you can then generate them again from the partial log with the "-ro" option.

Comment: @StephaneLandelle u mean run the gatling job again with -ro command line option?

Comment: Yes, see doc: http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.6/general/configuration.html#command-line-options